# select query call a function which return varray in Oracle

Tags: oracle, select, plsql, oracle11g, varray

I want to create a function which return VArray and populate the values in select query.

**My VArray is:**

```
create  type array_squad_t is varray(2) of VARCHAR2(200);
```

**My function is**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_varray(
  id number
  )
    RETURN array_squad_t
IS
    v_array array_squad_t;
BEGIN
  v_array(1) := '1 Val';
  v_array(2) := '2 Val';
    RETURN v_array;
END;
```

**I want to call it like**

```
SELECT column_value1, column_value2, e.Name FROM employees e, TABLE ( test_varray(1) );
```

**Expected Result:**

```
column_value1 | column_value2 | Name
1 Val         | 2 Val         | SomeName
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you must initialize your collection appropriately with a constructor `array_squad_t()`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_varray(
  id number
  )
    RETURN array_squad_t
IS
    v_array array_squad_t := array_squad_t() ;
BEGIN
  v_array.extend(2);
  v_array(1) := '1 Val';
  v_array(2) := '2 Val';
    RETURN v_array;
END;
```

You can then use the `TABLE` function and `column_value` to fetch from the `varray` in a select statement like this.

```
SELECT
    column_value,
    e.*
FROM
    employees e,
    TABLE ( test_varray(1) );
```

Comment: It worked for me, thank you very much. but we are getting data in 1 column 2 rows (as array size is 2), can we get data in 2 separate columns.

Comment: @PramendraRaghuwanshi : Could you please elaborate? or better  update the question with expected result.